# How to access elements of an xml file within a java class that is not an activity?

Tags: android

I have a java class (not an activity). From it, I want to access an ImageView within an xml file which is not the layout file for any activity. The id of the ImageView is `image_view`. I have many xml files in my app with ImageViews with ids `image_view`. How can I access the ImageView in that specific xml file from my java class?

Here is my code:

```java
    package com.example.treeapp;

    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.ImageView;

    import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.URL;

    public class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        private ImageView imageView; // I want to set this ImageView

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... strings) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
                return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openStream());
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("cs50", "Download image error", e);
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
```

And here is my xml file

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:background="#ffbb00">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/left_guideline_view"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".12077"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/right_guideline_view"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".87923"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/left_guideline_image_view"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".16908"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/right_guideline_image_view"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".32367"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/top_guideline_image_view"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".14706"
            android:orientation="horizontal"/>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/bottom_guideline_image_view"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".61765"
            android:orientation="horizontal"/>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/left_guideline_text_view"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".37198"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/right_guideline_text_view"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".72222"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/top_guideline_text_view_order"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".13235"
            android:orientation="horizontal"/>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/bottom_guideline_text_view_order"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".38235"
            android:orientation="horizontal"/>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/bottom_guideline_text_view_donor"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".61765"
            android:orientation="horizontal"/>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/left_guideline_send_image_icon"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".32367"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/right_guideline_send_image_icon"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".43961"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/top_guideline_icon"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".74265"
            android:orientation="horizontal"/>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/bottom_guideline_icon"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".96324"
            android:orientation="horizontal"/>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/left_guideline_message_icon"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".58696"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/right_guideline_message_icon"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".70290"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/left_border"
            android:background="#ffbb00"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/left_guideline_view"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#ffbb00" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/right_border"
            android:background="#ffbb00"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/right_guideline_view"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#ffbb00" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/middle"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/left_guideline_view"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/right_guideline_view"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/order_planter_message_shape" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/image_view"
            android:background="@drawable/profile_picture_shape"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/left_guideline_image_view"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/right_guideline_image_view"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/top_guideline_image_view"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/bottom_guideline_image_view"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/text_view_order"
            android:text="Plant # Trees"
            android:fontFamily="@font/inter_semibold"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textColor="#6633ff"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/left_guideline_text_view"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/right_guideline_text_view"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/top_guideline_text_view_order"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/bottom_guideline_text_view_order"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/text_view_donor"
            android:text="David Malan, $20"
            android:fontFamily="@font/inter_regular"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="#6633ff"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/left_guideline_text_view"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/right_guideline_text_view"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_guideline_text_view_order"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/bottom_guideline_text_view_donor"/>

        <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/send_image_icon"
            app:lottie_fileName="28699-photo-icon.json"
            app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
            app:lottie_loop="true"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/left_guideline_send_image_icon"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/right_guideline_send_image_icon"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/top_guideline_icon"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/bottom_guideline_icon"/>

        <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/message_icon"
            app:lottie_fileName="28699-photo-icon.json"
            app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
            app:lottie_loop="true"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/left_guideline_message_icon"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/right_guideline_message_icon"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/top_guideline_icon"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/bottom_guideline_icon"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: There is no `ImageView` object in your layout files. Those are just blueprints for objects created at runtime. If you need to set an image on a particular `ImageView`, you'll need a reference to that runtime object, wherever you're using it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably I'm wrong, but my suggestion is this:

```
public class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    private ImageView imageView; // I want to set this ImageView
    public DownloadImageTask(Context context){
      View view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.your_layout, null);
      imageView = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.image_view);
    }
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openStream());
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("cs50", "Download image error", e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```